# Local behavior of a finite cover above the branch locus

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\rightarrow S$ be a normal scheme, proper and smooth in relative dimension 1 over $S$. Let $g : S\rightarrow X$ be a section. Let $X^\circ := X - g(S)$ be obtained by removing the section. Let $p^\circ : Y^\circ\rightarrow X^\circ$ be finite etale of degree $d$. Taking the normalization of $X$ inside $Y^\circ$ gives a factorization
$$Y^\circ\subset Y\stackrel{\nu}{\rightarrow} X$$

where $\nu$ is finite of degree $d$. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of the section $g(S)$, then by normality, the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is a DVR with uniformizer $t$ and residue field $k$, so we may form the completion $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}}$, which barring trivial cases will be an equicharacteristic complete DVR.

I want to say that $Y\times_X \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}}$ is Spec $A$, where $A$ decomposes as a direct product $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ where each $A_i$ is an extension of $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}}$ of the form $k_i[[t^{1/e}]]$, where $[k_i:k] = f_i$ is finite, and $d = \sum_{i=1}^n f_ie_i$

Is this true? Can Mohan's example occur in this situation?

EDIT: Okay, so I believe that it is true, and that Mohan's example can't occur, because of the following:

Let $R := \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ with fraction field $K$. By the definition of the normalization, the stalk of $Y$ above $\eta$ (ie, the global sections of $Y\times_X R$) is precisely the integral closure of $R$ inside the stalk of $Y^\circ$ above $\eta$. However, $Y^\circ \rightarrow X$ is flat, so the stalk of $Y^\circ$ over $\eta$ contains $t^{-1}$, but it's also an etale $R$-algebra, and $R[t^{-1}] = K$, so it's actually an etale $K$-algebra, which decomposes as a direct sum of separable field extensions of $K$. Thus, the stalk of $Y$ above $\eta$ is the normalization of $R$ inside a direct sum of fields which is just the direct sum of the normalizations inside each field, each of which must be integrally closed, hence a DVR. The result follows by taking completions.

Comment: What if $A=k[[u^2,u^3]]$ and $t\mapsto u^2$?

Comment: @Mohan God damnit, nice example. I've edited the post to ask what I was really asking...

Comment: @Mohan Ok I think I have a proof, what do you think?